# How can I fix spring boot to serve my static files from ROOT after upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

Recently, I upgraded my spring boot version from 2.2.6 to 2.6.1.  After the upgrade, the server no longer finds my files in ROOT.   The static files are built from an angular project which is added to my ROOT.war file at build time and the war file is moved to my server.

On the server, my static files are located at tomcat/webapps/ROOT.  Previously (before upgrading) my files were found here and there were no issues.  Since the upgrade typing myurl.com returns 404 but will return if I type myurl.com/index.html.  I've tried to set up the WebMvcConfigurer for example

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
   registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
   .addResourceLocations("/");
}
```

I added to my application.properties
`spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher`
I also added `server.servlet.register-default-servlet=true` thinking it was the DefaultServlet removal that caused the issue but this didn't make any difference.

In the logs, I can see the ResourceHttpRequestHandler is mapped to [classpath[META-INF/resources], classpath[resources/], classpath[static/], classpath[public], ServletContext[/]]

The logs also indicate the Resource is not found.

I can move the files to webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classpath/static and they show up but I was hoping to avoid messing with the build process.  Was there a change in the framework to disable root level static file serving or am I missing something?